# what are the techniques for displaying the internal frame?

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

what are the techniques for displaying the `JInternalFrame`?

```
Follow f = new Follow();
```

`Follow` is my `JInternalFrame` and i want to print that on `JFrame`. In `JFrame`there is already one `JInternalFrame` is running. and i want to print this `JInternalFrame` over that like `ConfirmDialog`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/** Simple example illustrating the use of internal frames.
 * 
 */

public class JInternalFrames extends JFrame {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new JInternalFrames();
  }

  public JInternalFrames() {
    super("Multiple Document Interface");
    WindowUtilities.setNativeLookAndFeel();
    addWindowListener(new ExitListener());
    Container content = getContentPane();
    content.setBackground(Color.white);
    JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
    desktop.setBackground(Color.white);
    content.add(desktop, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setSize(450, 400);
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
      JInternalFrame frame
        = new JInternalFrame(("Internal Frame " + i),
                             true, true, true, true);
      frame.setLocation(i*50+10, i*50+10);
      frame.setSize(200, 150);
      frame.setBackground(Color.white);
      desktop.add(frame);
      frame.moveToFront();
    }
    setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

[image]

One more tutorial is on [Java Tutorials Code Sample – InternalFrameDemo.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/InternalFrameDemoProject/src/components/InternalFrameDemo.java)